# Displaying syntax highlighted code

Tags: plugins, syntax-highlighting

I have a blog that I write up entries for that sometimes has programming code as part of the text within my writing's. Normally I use the quote function to give it a bit of highlighting, but was wondering if there's a better way that anyone has come across in their travels. Something that could do this for example:

```
function foo() {
     $var = "bar";
}
```

to highlight various property for the code like an IDE would.

Thought that this would have been asked before, but after searching didn't have any luck, so thought I'd ask. Thanks for anyone that can offer some help on this matter.

Comment: Try and Google "syntax highlighter wordpress plugins".

Answer (score 2):

Try [SyntaxHighlighter Evolved](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/). I believe it will work for your needs.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you might be using R. If that's true, you can use this from visual:

```
[sourcecode language="r"]
function foo() {
     $var = "bar";
}
[/sourcecode]
```

Comment: I believe that shortcode is native to WP.com but not to stand-alone WP installs...

Comment: Nope it's PHP, not R.